# Merge in db2 error for invalid attributes

Tags: sql, merge, db2

I'm using a newly created merge statement to perform UPSERTS in db2.

I think the structure is correct but the problem is I get the error

`sqlstate[42000] syntax or access violation: Attributes not valid`

I'm not sure exactly where the issue is because it's not very explicit but it seems like maybe it's coming from one of my values?

the merge:

```
MERGE INTO STATUS as S
    USING (VALUES(
                CAST(:ORDER as INT),
                CAST(:STATUS as VARCHAR),
                CAST(:IS_ACTIVE as DECIMAL(1,0)),
                CAST(:DATE_UPDATED as DATE)
                )
            )
    AS O(order, status, is_active, date_updated)    
    ON o.order = S.order_id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET order_status = status, is_active = is_active, date_updated = date_updated
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES(order, status, is_active, date_updated)
```

Comment: What application type runs this statement?

Comment: I'm running this in php for db2 7.2. Running the command in powershell

Comment: Try to cast parameters explicitly to the corresponding data types. Like `values (cast (:order as int), ...`

Comment: Hmm, I've done that now (updated my answer) and still getting it. The data types do match the actual column data type as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB2 for iSeries manual https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzmerge.htm has the following example.

```
MERGE INTO employee AS t
   USING (VALUES(CAST(? AS CHAR(6)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(12)),
                      CAST(? AS CHAR(1)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(15)),
                      CAST(? AS SMALLINT), CAST(? AS INTEGER)))
          s (empno, firstnme, midinit, lastname, edlevel, salary)
   ON t.empno = s.empno
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET salary = s.salary
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT (empno, firstnme, midinit, lastname, edlevel, salary)
            VALUES (s.empno, s.firstnme, s.midinit, s.lastname, s.edlevel,
                    s.salary)
```

Maybe you need to qualify the attribute names in the `SET` and the final `VALUES` statement.

E.g. saying `is_active = is_active` rather than `is_active = O.is_active` is probably confusing for DB2

Comment: I did this and still had the error, however, adding VARCHAR(45) rather than just VARCHAR() resolved it! Thanks for your help!